# gcc failed when pip upgrading pyzmq

Tags: python-2.7, redhat

I work under CentOS 5.6. And I have both

gcc(gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52))

and gcc44(gcc44 (GCC) 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3))

on /usr/bin/.

When I did pip install -U pyzmq, I received the following error message:

```
Downloading/unpacking pyzmq from https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pyzmq/pyzmq-14.3.1.tar.gz#md5=7196b4a6fbf98022f17ffa924be3d68d
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pyzmq

    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/build'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/gh-pages'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'bundled/zeromq/src/Makefile*'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'setup.cfg'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'zmq/libzmq*'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '__pycache__/*' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.deps/*' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.DS_Store' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.mailmap' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching 'Makefile.am' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching 'Makefile.in' found anywhere in distribution
Installing collected packages: pyzmq
  Found existing installation: pyzmq 2.1.11
    Uninstalling pyzmq:
      Successfully uninstalled pyzmq
  Running setup.py install for pyzmq
    Using bundled libzmq
    already have bundled/zeromq
    already have platform.hpp
    checking for timer_create
    ************************************************
    ************************************************
    cc -c /tmp/timer_createbuFGwC.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/tmp/timer_createbuFGwC.o
    unable to execute cc: No such file or directory
    no timer_create, linking librt
    Using bundled libsodium
    already have bundled/libsodium
    already have version.h
    already have crypto_stream_salsa20.h
    already have crypto_scalarmult_curve25519.h
    ************************************************
    ************************************************
    building 'zmq.libsodium' extension
    /usr/bin/gcc44 -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DNATIVE_LITTLE_ENDIAN=1 -Ibundled/libsodium/src/libsodium/include -Ibundled/libsodium/src/libsodium/include/sodium -I/opt/python27/include/python2.7 -c buildutils/initlibsodium.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/buildutils/initlibsodium.o
    buildutils/initlibsodium.c:10:20: error: Python.h: No such file or directory
    buildutils/initlibsodium.c:12: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘Methods’
    buildutils/initlibsodium.c:40: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘initlibzmq’
    error: command '/usr/bin/gcc44' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /opt/python27/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools;__file__='/home/fzeng/build/pyzmq/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-90NjCM-record/install-record.txt:
    running install

running build

running build_py

running build_ext

running configure

Using bundled libzmq

already have bundled/zeromq

already have platform.hpp

checking for timer_create

************************************************

************************************************

cc -c /tmp/timer_createbuFGwC.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/tmp/timer_createbuFGwC.o

unable to execute cc: No such file or directory

no timer_create, linking librt

Using bundled libsodium

already have bundled/libsodium

already have version.h

already have crypto_stream_salsa20.h

already have crypto_scalarmult_curve25519.h

************************************************

************************************************

building 'zmq.libsodium' extension

/usr/bin/gcc44 -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DNATIVE_LITTLE_ENDIAN=1 -Ibundled/libsodium/src/libsodium/include -Ibundled/libsodium/src/libsodium/include/sodium -I/opt/python27/include/python2.7 -c buildutils/initlibsodium.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/buildutils/initlibsodium.o

buildutils/initlibsodium.c:10:20: error: Python.h: No such file or directory

buildutils/initlibsodium.c:12: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘Methods’

buildutils/initlibsodium.c:40: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘initlibzmq’

error: command '/usr/bin/gcc44' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
  Rolling back uninstall of pyzmq
Command /opt/python27/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools;__file__='/home/fzeng/build/pyzmq/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-90NjCM-record/install-record.txt failed with error code 1 in /home/fzeng/build/pyzmq
Storing complete log in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Same problem for me on Ubuntu 14.04 with i686-linux-gnu-gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2

Answer (score 9):

I ran into the exact same error while trying this pip command:

```
pip install "ipython[notebook]
```

The full error is below:

```
/usr/bin/gcc44 -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 
-Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DNATIVE_LITTLE_ENDIAN=1 
-Ibundled/libsodium/src/libsodium/include 
-Ibundled/libsodium/src/libsodium/include/sodium 
-I/opt/python27/include/python2.7 -c buildutils/initlibsodium.c 
-o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/buildutils/initlibsodium.o

buildutils/initlibsodium.c:10:20: error: Python.h: No such file or directory
```

The error says the compiler (gcc44) could not find the header file Python.h in /opt/python27/include/python2.7. (In my build, it was looking in /usr/include/python2.7.) Since I'm on Ubuntu, that led me down the path of trying to find which package I needed to install in order to bring in the Python header files.

Searching around, [I found out](http://forum.gns3.net/topic9704.html) that I needed to install the python-dev package. I'm sure there will be a corresponding package in yum (CentOS), but on my Ubuntu machine, I typed:

```
apt-get install python-dev
```

After that, I had Python.h in that include directory, and I was able to complete the build.